# Express and Node, http call returns an array that is undefined when it's elements are called

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm currently working my way through FreeCodeCamp's Back-End Development certification. I've gotten to the Image Search Abstraction microservice ([link](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/image-search-abstraction-layer)) and I'm using Node and Express for the backend code. I've made an http request to  Google Custom Search api with the [Request library](https://github.com/request/request) and I'm able to make use of the returned data except for arrays of objects. The code I've written to put all the data into a returnable object is:

```
request(url,function(err,result,body) {
var images = [];
var data = JSON.parse(body);
data.items.forEach(function(val) {
  var obj = {
    image: val.pagemap.cse_image[0].src,
    text: val.snippet,
    source: val.link
  }
  images.push(obj);
})
res.send(images);
```

The issue I'm running into is the `val.pagemap.cse_image[0].src`. My localserver crashes when the request is made because:

```
image: typeof val.pagemap.cse_image[0],
                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

`val.pagemap.cse_image` returns:

```
image: [
  {
    src: "http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/masonry/001/172/636/cfd.gif"
  }
],
```

`typeof val.pagemap.cse_image` returns 'object' and `Array.isArray(val.pagemap.cse_image)` returns true. But anything added to the end results in it return undefined. Even `.length` throws an undefined error.

Why is the array an array when it's called by itself but as soon as I try to try to call one if it's properties it's undefined?

Comment: What is the actual url you're requesting? The one at the page you linked to does not seem to reply with an object containing an `items` property, I just see an array of objects.

Comment: `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={API_KEY}&num=10&cx={CSE_ID}&searchtype=image&q={TERM}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `val.pagemap.cse_image` in fact contains this:

```
image: [
  {
    src: "http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/masonry/001/172/636/cfd.gif"
  }
],
```

then you need to instead access `val.pagemap.cse_image.image[0].src`.

Otherwise the problem may be that not *all* of your `items`' `pagemap` objects have a `cse_image` property.

Comment: This was it. The image key was actually part of the object I created to display the information for the user. But throwing an if statement in there to check that cse_image existed solved the problem. Thank you so much.